# On what type of data is `prcomp` to be used?

Tags: r, pca

I am currently learning about PCA and `prcomp` in R. What I'm struggling to understand is exactly what type of statistical data we're supposed to use `prcomp` on (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136090/163242)). Do we just take our raw data and immediately use `prcomp` on it? Or do we first calculate a covariance matrix and then use `prcomp` on that?

Comment: `prcomp` used to use as input row data, then the algorithm itself computes the matrices!

Comment: @Duck I don't understand what you mean. Are you telling me what `prcomp` did in the *past*?

Comment: First you use some data then `prcomp(x)` compute the matrix and then obtain eigen values and compute components!

Comment: So we apply `prcomp` directly to the data, rather than first using the data to compute the covariance matrix, and *then* applying `prcomp` to the covariance matrix?

Comment: Yes what you said is right!

Comment: @Duck Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the clarification!